# Renew DHCP Lease without knowing if en0 or en1

Tags: dhcp, ipconfig

Dear Superuser Community,

I'm writing on a a script that renews the DHCP Lease. To function correctly on other computers, how can renew the DHCP Lease **without knowing if en0 or en1 is active**.

Is it ok to reset both: sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP; sudo ipconfig set en1 DHCP?

Edit: The OS is OSX El Capitan (Sorry, I forgot the most important info)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS is this for?

Comment: It's for OSX El Capitan (Sorry I missed that)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, as long as both interfaces are defined in /etc/network/interfaces running the command on both should be fine.

EDIT: I assumed this was a Linux question based on the use of sudo. It may be useful to add this to your question since ipconfig is a Windows command.

Comment: It's for OSX El Capitan - thanks for the hint, I added this in my question

Comment: I believe the info in my answer is still correct for OSX however Mac isn't my strong point so I'm not entirely sure.